# Question about the number of endomorphisms/automorphisms of finite cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $A,B,C$ are finite cyclic groups such that $A = B \times C$, where the orders of $B$ and $C$ are $p$ and $p^2$ respectively, where $p$ is a prime. What are the orders of $End(A)$ and $Aut(A)$?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but how can $A,B,C$ be cyclic and at the same time $A=B\times C$, $|B|=p$, $|C|=p^2$. The cyclic group of order $p^3$ ($A$) is not isomorphic to the direct product of the cyclic groups of orders $p$ and $p^2$...

Comment: If $A=B\times C$ where $B,C$ have orders $p,p^2$ resp. then $A$ cannot be cyclic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure have a lot of questions:

Hint:

1. $\text{Hom}(X\times Y,Z)\cong\text{Hom}(X,Z)\times\text{Hom}(Y,Z)$ and $\text{Hom}(X,Y\times Z)\cong\text{Hom}(X,Y)\times\text{Hom}(X,Z)$.
2. $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}_a,\mathbb{Z}_b)\cong\mathbb{Z}_{(a,b)}$.

Comment: I'm preparing for an exam, and need to have all doubts cleared! Also, what does this notation mean: $\mathbb{Z}_{(a,b)}$ ?

Comment: $(a,b)=\text{gcd}(a,b)$.

Comment: @Alex Youcis: Do you have a proof-reference for "2." above?

Comment: @Alex Youcis: Do you have a proof-reference for "1." above?

Comment: @Alex Youcis: Are you sure that $\text{Hom}(X\times Y,Z)\equiv \text{Hom}(X,Z)\times \text{Hom}(Y,Z)$ holds also for non-abelian $Z$?